# Searching for similar values within a regex string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to do a search with regex within two lists that have similar strings, but not the same, how to fix the fault below?

**Script:**

```
import re

list1 = [
'juice',
'potato']

list2 = [
'juice;44',
'potato;55',
'apple;66']

correlation = []
for a in list1:
    r = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(a), re.I)
    for b in list2:
        if r.search(b):
            pass
        else:
            correlation.append(b)

print(correlation)
```

**Output:**

```
['potato;55', 'apple;66', 'juice;44', 'apple;66']
```

**Desired Output:**

```
['apple;66']
```

**Regex:**

[image]

Comment: You search each item of `list1` in each item of `list2` and if e.g. `'juice'` isn't in `'potato;55'` it is added to `correlation`.

Comment: how do you recommend doing?

Comment: Set a flag to `False` before the inner for-loop, set it in the inner loop to `True` if you found a match, after the loop add to `correlation` if flag is `False` yet.

Comment: I understand the logic, but could you please provide a snippet of code as an example? Please

Comment: Oops, I think I oversaw something. Do you also want to find elements in `list1` not contained in `list2`? If so, things are a bit more complicated.

Comment: I just want to search what's on list 2 that doesn't exist on list 1

Comment: The fastest gun in the West won again. You may want to look at the other, arguably better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a single regex pattern to match terms from `list1` as whole words, and then use `filter`:

```
import re

list1 = ['juice', 'potato']
list2 = ['juice;44', 'potato;55', 'apple;66']

rx = re.compile(r'\b(?:{})\b'.format("|".join(list1)))
print( list(filter(lambda x: not rx.search(x), list2)) )
# => ['apple;66']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/XtVDx8).

The regex is `\b(?:juice|potato)\b`, see [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z3WV2W/1/). The `\b` is a word boundary, the regex matches `juice` or `potato` as whole words. `filter(lambda x: not rx.search(x), list2)` removes all items from `list2` that match the regex.

Answer (score 1):

First, inner and outer for-loop must be swapped to make this work.

Then you can set a flag to `False` before the inner for-loop, set it in the inner loop to `True` if you found a match, after the loop add to `correlation` if flag is `False` yet.

This finally looks like:

```
import re

list1 = [
'juice',
'potato']

list2 = [
'juice;44',
'potato;55',
'apple;66']

correlation = []
for b in list2:
    found = False

    for a in list1:
        r = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(a), re.I)
        if r.search(b):
            found = True

    if not found:
        correlation.append(b)

print(correlation)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert `list1` into a single regexp that matches all the words. Then append the element of `list2` if it doesn't match the regexp.

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in ROE) + r')\b')
correlation = [a for a in list2 if not regex.search(a)]
```

Comment: If you use `re.escape`, you cannot rely on `\b` as word boundaries. In this case, you should use `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` as word boundaries since you assume that "words" may start/end with special characters.

Comment: Good point. I just use `re.escape()` habitually whenever the input data is supposed to be matched literally, to prevent errors from embedded punctuation.

Comment: If the input words begin or end with punctuation, I'm not even sure what the expected result is supposed to be.